# DataTable.Select throws EvaluateException: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Double and System.String

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I am importing data from multiple spread sheets into a single database table.

To start I've loaded the entire excel file into a data set, 1 page = 1 table.  I then looped over all the pages and added the columns to the new combination table.  Finally, I will take each row, find the corresponding row in the other pages and copy the data into a new row in the new table.  I need to use a combination of 3 columns to perform this match: 'Brand', 'Model' and 'Yr'.  Here is the loop for the last step.

```
//Add Data
foreach (DataRow drBase in tableSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{               
    List<DataRow> drSelect = new List<DataRow>(); //selected rows for specific bike
    foreach(DataTable dt in tableSet.Tables)
    {
        string expression="";
        foreach (string colName in joiningCols)
        {
            if (drBase[colName].ToString() == "") break;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression))
            {
                expression += " and ";
            }

            expression += string.Format("{0} = '{1}'",colName, drBase[colName].ToString().Trim());
        }
        DataRow[] temp= { };
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(expression))
        {
        temp = dt.Select(expression);   //This is the line throwing the exception                     
        }

        if (temp.Length == 1)
        {
            drSelect.Add(temp[0]);
            //Debug.Print(string.Format("Match found {0} on {1}", expression, dt.TableName));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Print(string.Format("Incorrect number of matches ({2}) to <{1}> on Table[{0}]", dt.TableName, expression, temp.Length));
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (drSelect.Count == 2)
    {
        DataRow current = resultTable.NewRow();

        for (int t = 0; t < tableSet.Tables.Count; t++)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in tableSet.Tables[t].Columns)
            current[c.ColumnName] = drSelect[t][c.ColumnName];
        }

        resultTable.Rows.Add(current);
    }                
}
```

The exception is:

```
EvaluateException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Double and System.String.
```

The value of 'expression' during the exception is "Brand = 'BMW' and Yr = '1997-2000' and Model = 'F 650'"

The error, and my research, say that I should enclose all the values as strings, which I've done.  None of the columns in excel use a special format, so all should default to text.  The only column that may contain only numbers is the year, but since it was able to do several iterations  before stopping I do not believe the error is pointing to another row.

After some testing, where I broke up the expression into parts (A, B and C) it only crashed when selecting on A and C ("Brand = 'BMW' and Yr = '1997-2000'")  Not when I select by each clause individually.

What am I missing?  Where is this double it is trying to compare?

Comment: I don't use datatables at all, so this is a shot in the dark.  In your `expression` variable, you use `and`.  If this is C# syntax, should that be `&&` instead?  Again, I'm not a datatable user.

Comment: @Hambone No, DataTable uses an sql-like syntax.  The issue has something to do with the single quotes, probably over the Yr column because it might look like numbers.

Comment: Are you entirely sure none of the excel columns are double?

Comment: Yes, all are general

Answer (score 0):

"Excel File"

Treat everything as a string.  I put my results into a simple class, with "String" properties that are settable..and then have a corresponding "get" property with the correct datatype.
Then I can run queries/filters against it.

```
public class ExcelImportRow
{
    public string SalaryString { get; set; }

    /* if zero is ok */
    public double Salary
    {
        get
        {
            double returnValue = 0.00D;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SalaryString))
            {
                double.TryParse(this.SalaryString, out returnValue);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    public string TaxRateString { get; set; }

    /* if zero is not ok */
    public decimal? TaxRate
    {
        get
        {
            decimal? returnValue = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TaxRateString))
            {
                decimal tryParseResult;
                if (decimal.TryParse(this.TaxRateString, out tryParseResult))
                {
                    returnValue = tryParseResult;
                }
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I feel this solution doesn't fix my needs.  I am using ExcelDataReader because of the number of columns involved.  This library imports to a dataset, and my result is a dataset.

Comment: Its the same issue.  Everything in your untyped dataset is a string.  I would take your dataset and convert it to an ICollection<ExcelImportRow> objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"Yr >= 1997 and Yr =< 2000"
```

You're still fighting a "guess the datatype" battle.

I still suggest the transform to an `ICollection<MyHolderObject>`

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not a database. In Excel any worksheet cell can contain any type of data.

I'm not familiar with Excel Data Reader, but it likely uses the same sort of fuzzy logic as the Excel ODBC/OLE drivers, i.e.: there is a RowsToScan parameter that tells the driver how many non-heading rows it should scan to **guess** a data type for each column, the default being 1 row.

REF: [Excel ODBC Driver May Determine Wrong Data Type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141284)

What's probably happening with your Excel file is that the first few rows contain numeric data in the Yr column, so Excel Data Reader is inferring the Yr data type to be Decimal (and it/something else is setting that data type on your DataTable's Yr column). When you get to the row containing '1997-2000' that value cannot be converted to a Decimal, hence your exception: the DataTable[Yr] column is of type Decimal, your comparison value is of type String.